# Curve on a surface, calculating the steepest ascent in every point moving on the curve.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, curves, surfaces

Note: Steepest ascent is from google translate, let me know if it makes no sense or there's another word to call it (I mean when the directional derivative is on the direction of the gradient vector)

> Let $S$ be a surface with the function $z=f(x,y)=10-2x^2-y^2$, from a point starts a curve $L$ that is given by the parametric presentation: $x(t)=e^{-4t}$, $y(t)=2e^{-2t}$, $z(t)=10-2e^{-8t}-4e^{-4t}$. 
> Prove that in every point on the curve, the vector that is pointing in the direction of the steepest ascent in every point $M$ that is traveling on $L$ is : $(f_x(x,y),f_y(x,y),|\nabla f(x,y)|^2)$, what is your conclusion?

I know how to proof this for a specific point $M(x_0,y_0,f(x_0,y_0))$, by finding the gradient vector using the dot product with a vector that is vertical to the gradient vector in a specific point $M$. 
I'm not sure though how to do it in general, the only approach I have is building $f(x(t),y(t))$, but also I'm not sure how to continue, I would be needing to write a general gradient vector for every point on $L$, I'm not sure how to move on with so many generalizations and feeling a little lost. 
About the conclusion, I know that it must be that in every point $M$ the direction of the steepest ascent is the direction of the gradient vector.

Any tips or hints and feedback about my thinking and logic would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Once you build the function $g(t)=f(x(t), y(t))$, what is its derivative (obv. with respect to $t$)?

Comment: @wisefool $g'(t)=f_x(x,y)x'(t) + f_y(x,y)y'(t)$, if I haven't made mistakes, I'm getting a little lost though, what does $f(x(t),y(t))$ mean? is it the same as $L$? when I took $g'(t)$ do I just get normal derivative of one variable function that returns the slope? I think I must first of all understand all of these stuff before solving

Comment: I am not very clear on the question. Is M a point moving on the surface S? Can you double check the equation of the surface and the curve?

Comment: @MathLover I'm really sorry, thanks for pointing this out, I edited $z(t)$ in the curve equation. About the point $M$, I'm sorry about my bad translation, I will try to link the all the question how it was here, first there was $S$ surface and I was asked to prove that for $M(x_0,y_0,z(x_0,y_0))$ the vector pointing to the steepest ascent is the one I wrote above but with $x_0,y_0$.. then, I was asked to prove that the all the curve $L$ is on the surface $S$ (I just substitued in the equation of surface), and then I was asked what I wrote above, to prove that for every point on the curve..

Comment: the vector pointing in the direction of the steepest ascent is (what I wrote in the question), while $M$ is traveling on the curve $L$. (I tried to cut all those parts to make the question more straight to the point)

Comment: Yes now the curve is on the surface. But there is something more that is amiss here because $(f_x(x,y),f_y(x,y),|\nabla f(x,y)|^2)$ is actually a vector perpendicular to the direction of steepest ascent at that point.  In other words, it is the direction of the tangent vector to the curve.

Comment: @MathLover Wait a minute, the steepest ascent is like the "biggest slope" or that's what google translate said, for example solving the first question with specific point $M$, I said that it is the gradient vector itself, and I found it. (like the maximum value for the directional derivative)

Comment: What is the value you got for the gradient vector?

Comment: @MathLover $\nabla f = (f_x(x_0,y_0),f_y(x_0,y_0),C)$ is the gradient vector for $f$. now a vector that is vertical to $\nabla f$ in point $M(x_0,y_0,f(x_0,y_0)$ is, by using the gradient vector again: $\nabla (f(x_0,y_0)-z)=(f_x(x_0,y_0),f_y(x_0,y_0),-1)$, and then I did the dot product between both that should be zero. and got that $C=f_x(x_0,y_0)^2 + f_y(x_0,y_0)^2=|\nabla f(x_0,y_0)|^2$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124293/discussion-between-math-lover-and-pwaol).